# AES-CMAC using mbedtls: undefined reference error

Tags: c++, mbedtls, cmac

I try to implement AES-CMAC using mbedTLS.
I get some errors:

> undefined reference to `mbedtls_cipher_cmac_starts`, undefined reference to `mbedtls_cipher_cmac_update`, undefined reference to `mbedtls_cipher_cmac_finish`,

Why could these functions not be resolved, even though `mbedtls_cipher_init` and `mbedtls_cipher_setup` could?

BTW. I implemented AES under the same project using mbedTLS with no problem. I use Eclipse Nano.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "openssl/evp.h"
#include "openssl/cmac.h"
#include "mbedtls/cmac.h"
#include "mbedtls/cipher.h"
using namespace std;
unsigned char key[16]={0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

int main()
{
    unsigned char m[100],m_len=32;
    unsigned char out[16],out1[16],out2[16];
    size_t d_len;

    int i,ret;
    mbedtls_cipher_context_t m_ctx;
    const mbedtls_cipher_info_t *cipher_info;
    cipher_info = mbedtls_cipher_info_from_type( MBEDTLS_CIPHER_AES_128_ECB );
    if(cipher_info==NULL)
        printf("\nmbedtls_cipher_info_from_type failed");

    mbedtls_cipher_init(&m_ctx);

    ret=mbedtls_cipher_setup( &m_ctx, cipher_info );
    printf("\n mbedtls_cipher_setup returned %d %d",ret,     m_ctx.cipher_info->type);



    ret=mbedtls_cipher_cmac_starts(&m_ctx,key,128);
    printf("\n mbedtls_cipher_cmac_starts returned %d",ret);

    ret= mbedtls_cipher_cmac_update(&m_ctx, m,m_len);
    printf("\n mbedtls_cipher_cmac_update returned %d",ret);

    ret=mbedtls_cipher_cmac_finish(&m_ctx,out1);
    printf("\n mbedtls_cipher_cmac_starts returned %d",ret);
    d_len=16;
    printf("\nLength is %d\n",(int)d_len);
    for(i=0;i<d_len;i++)
    {
        printf("%x ",out1[i]);
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: CAUTION: I corrected an error here ```cipher_info = mbedtls_cipher_info_from_type(MBEDTLS_CIPHER_AES_128_ECB);``` has to be ECB mode and _not_ CBC mode, c.f. https://tls.mbed.org/api/cmac_8h.html#ae5835d528bbfec2ae2452ba4617469b8

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, CMAC is disabled in the [default configuration](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/mbedtls-2.4/include/mbedtls/config.h#L1673). If other crypto functions are found, but not the CMAC functions, this must be because the CMAC functions weren't included in your build.

Edit `config.h` to uncomment `#define MBEDTLS_CMAC_C` and rebuild the library.